# How to fix Raster Dataset with numbers in Extent that look like latitude/longuitude but say metres?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system

In ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1, the Spatial Reference of my Raster Dataset reports that its units are metres (well meters) but the values look like decimal degrees e.g. -33 degrees is highly plausible but not -33 metres.

How can ArcGIS for Desktop be "told" that these numbers are degrees of latitude and longitude, rather than values in metres?

Comment: Would you be able to post a picture of you Raster Dataset Properties with the Extent and Spatial Reference visible on the General tab?  It sounds like someone may have defined a Projected Coordinate System on numbers from a Geographic Coordinate System.  If that is the case then the [**Define Projection**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) tool should be able to quickly solve it.

Comment: Ah cheers, define projection quickly solved it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized problem, and unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I voted to keep this open because I think it represents a common misunderstanding by new users of ArcGIS for Desktop (or new to working with Coordinate Systems).  I will edit it to make it more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the dataframe projection as a geographic one (e.g. WGS84) and add your projected raster layer (e.g. UTM WGS84 something) in such dataframe. If the raster layer has the right projection information associated, it will be reprojected *"on the fly"* in the dataframe (geographic) projection, otherwise (because they are missing or wrong), the Define Projection tool has to be applied on it in order to set the right coordinate system, as PolyGeo stated before.

Comment: I think his/her raster dataset probably has the wrong projection information associated with it, so it will be interesting to see more details from the asker.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incomplete. If the raster layer has NOT the right projection information associated (because they are missing or wrong), the Define Projection tool has to be applied on it in order to set the right coordinate system, as PolyGeo said before.

Comment: Don't be afraid to edit that into your answer - what we are about here is trying to make every question and every answer as useful as possible.

Comment: @PolyGeo Done! Thanks for your efforts in order to keep this question clearer as possible. I'm agree with you. This is a strategic question for new users.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a **Projected Coordinate System** was defined on numbers from a **Geographic Coordinate System**.

If that is the case then the **[Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000)** tool should be able to quickly solve it.